# Finding the longest ORF (open reading frame) in reading frame 2 in multiple sequences in a FASTA file

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I've seen some questions regarding issues in this area, but couldn't use it for my issue, despite trying to understand the Biopython methods for many hours.

I can do it with logic but I believe it's preferred to utilize Biopython.

I've tried utilizing a code I found:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\97254\Downloads\dna2.fasta")
sequences = {}
count = 0
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line[0] == '>':
        count += 1
        first_row = line.split()
        name = first_row[0][1:]
        sequences[name] = ''
    else:
        sequences[name] = sequences[name] + line

startP = re.compile('ATG')
for sequence in sequences.values():
    sequence = squence[1:]
    longest = (0,)
    for m in startP.finditer(sequence):
        if len(Seq.Seq(sequence)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)) > longest[0]:
            pro = Seq.Seq(sequence)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)
            longest = (len(sequence[m.start():m.start()+len(pro)*3+3]), 
            m.start(), 
            sequence[m.start():m.start()+len(pro)*3+3])
```

Should I use logic such as a for loop that iterates over the sequences in jumps of 3, or is there a Biopythonic way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to find start/stop codons too, checkout this https://github.com/chris-rands/CrUtils/blob/master/scripts/faTranslateBioPython.py

Answer (score 1):

The [BioPython Tutorial and Cookbook contains the following code for finding open reading frames](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc295):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("NC_005816.fna", "fasta")
table = 11
min_pro_len = 100

for strand, nuc in [(+1, record.seq), (-1, record.seq.reverse_complement())]:
    for frame in range(3):
        length = 3 * ((len(record)-frame) // 3) #Multiple of three
        for pro in nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"):
            if len(pro) >= min_pro_len:
                print("%s...%s - length %i, strand %i, frame %i" \
                      % (pro[:30], pro[-3:], len(pro), strand, frame))
```

Output:

```
GCLMKKSSIVATIITILSGSANAASSQLIP...YRF - length 315, strand 1, frame 0
KSGELRQTPPASSTLHLRLILQRSGVMMEL...NPE - length 285, strand 1, frame 1
GLNCSFFSICNWKFIDYINRLFQIIYLCKN...YYH - length 176, strand 1, frame 1
VKKILYIKALFLCTVIKLRRFIFSVNNMKF...DLP - length 165, strand 1, frame 1
NQIQGVICSPDSGEFMVTFETVMEIKILHK...GVA - length 355, strand 1, frame 2
RRKEHVSKKRRPQKRPRRRRFFHRLRPPDE...PTR - length 128, strand 1, frame 2
TGKQNSCQMSAIWQLRQNTATKTRQNRARI...AIK - length 100, strand 1, frame 2
QGSGYAFPHASILSGIAMSHFYFLVLHAVK...CSD - length 114, strand -1, frame 0
IYSTSEHTGEQVMRTLDEVIASRSPESQTR...FHV - length 111, strand -1, frame 0
WGKLQVIGLSMWMVLFSQRFDDWLNEQEDA...ESK - length 125, strand -1, frame 1
RGIFMSDTMVVNGSGGVPAFLFSGSTLSSY...LLK - length 361, strand -1, frame 1
WDVKTVTGVLHHPFHLTFSLCPEGATQSGR...VKR - length 111, strand -1, frame 1
LSHTVTDFTDQMAQVGLCQCVNVFLDEVTG...KAA - length 107, strand -1, frame 2
RALTGLSAPGIRSQTSCDRLRELRYVPVSL...PLQ - length 119, strand -1, frame 2
```

Since it is straight from the tutorial, I would consider this the most Biopythonic way to find ORFs. It also iterates over the sequences in "jumps of 3" but it uses the BioPython function `SeqIO.read()` to parse the fasta file.

Comment: I read that the read() fiction is for a single record, while I have many in a FASTA file.

Comment: Use `Bio.SeqIO.parse()` for a FASA file with multiple records. It returns a SeqRecord iterator, so you can do: `for record in  SeqIO.parse("NC_005816.fna", "fasta"): ...`

Comment: And the frame and the end of each output line (either `0`, `1` or `2`) shows from which reading frame each result is.

Comment: I used this code to iterate over each sequence and got legnths, but something is wrong in my code, since none of the lengths appear as an answer in the course's exam I'm taking. Can I show you the code somehow?

Comment: @random Create a new question, show what you tried, what output you got and which output you expected (see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: I truly am researching and asking questions only when I can't move forward.